# Parse rest call getting data from array of pointers

Tags: python, rest, parse-platform

In on of my Parse tables I have an array of pointers to another table. I want to get all of the data from the objects being pointed to with a rest call. I was able to use this on columns that contain only a single pointer, but I don't know how to handle an array. Thanks for any help!

```
import json,httplib,urllib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
params = urllib.urlencode({"include":"myPointerColumn"})
connection.connect()
connection.request('GET', '/1/classes/Message/specificObjectID?%s' % params, '', {
   "X-Parse-Application-Id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
 })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually turns out to work. Parse's "include" tag will return information about every pointer in the column specified. This code will work for both a column of pointers, or an array of pointers. I just can't spell haha. If you don't get any response and you think you should, check your spelling 10 times over. No error messages will be thrown if the column you specify doesn't exist.